# Firebase Cloud functions: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'after') in my deployed cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I just deployed a function and i keep getting this error in my console just after onDocumentWritten is triggered

```
2023-12-31 12:05:53.028 WAT
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'after')
2023-12-31 12:05:53.028 WAT
    at /workspace/index.js:13:36
2023-12-31 12:05:53.028 WAT
    at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v2/providers/firestore.js:239:16)
2023-12-31 12:05:53.028 WAT
    at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:141:25
2023-12-31 12:05:53.028 WAT
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

what am i doing wrong?

taking a log of the event object gives

```
{0: 10, 1000: 115, 1001: 101, 1002: 114, 1003: 95, 1004: 108, 1005: 97, 1006: 115, 1007: 116, 1008: 95, 1009: 108, 100: 83, 1010: 111, 1011: 10....... etc}
```

here's my function:

```
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const {onDocumentWritten} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

initializeApp();

// Trigger the function on user document change
exports.updateRecommendationsOnWrite = onDocumentWritten("users/{userId}",
    (event) => {
        logger.log(event)
        const userDoc = event.data.data();

        // Ensure that the user document has user_interests
        const userInterests = userDoc.user_interests || [];

        // Retrieve all users' interests from the database
        const allUsersSnapshot = userDoc.ref.parent.get();
        const allUsersData = allUsersSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());

        // Create a matrix of user interests (0: not interested, 1: interested)
        const interestsMatrix =
            allUsersData.map((userData) =>
                userData.user_interests.split(",")
                    .map((interest) => userInterests.includes(interest.trim()) ? 1 : 0),
            );

        // Run collaborative filtering to get recommendations
        const recommendations =
            recommend.cFilter(interestsMatrix, allUsersData.length - 1);

        // Extract details of recommended users
        const recommendedUsers =
            recommendations.map((index) => allUsersData[index].user_id).filter(Boolean);

        logger.log("Recommendations updated successfully");

        // Update the user_recommendations field in the user document
        userDoc.ref.update({
            user_recommendations: recommendedUsers,
        });
    });
```

this is a NodeJS Function.
I don't know why my event Object is strange and not containing the usual parameters

please help me out